# Change text color white setting from DatePicker in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a `EditText` in signup screen ,I'm using `DatePicker` for setting birthday ,I have set `EditText` color white still whenever I set a text its showing in black,

Please let me know if there is any way to show text-color in white .

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        if (year > currentYear || (monthOfYear > currentMonth && year == currentYear)
                || (dayOfMonth > currentDay && year == currentYear && monthOfYear == currentMonth)) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.str_valid_date), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else
            setBirthDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
```

Comment: try this, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fbWz242uPgM

Comment: please provide some relevant example

Comment: if any problem then tell me... i will provide..

Comment: Yes I have a problem, provide me some code.